# NoReverseMatch at /job Reverse for 'job_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jobs/(?P<job_id>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: django, django-urls

I am getting this error in Django:NoReverseMatch at /job
Reverse for 'job_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jobs/(?P<job_id>[0-9]+)$']

My view is below:

```
def job(request):
    jobs = Job.objects.filter(status=Job.ACTIVE).order_by('-created_at')[0:3]
    services = Service.objects.filter(status=Service.ACTIVE).order_by('-created_at')[0:3]

    return render(request,'job/jobs.html',{'jobs':jobs ,'services':services})
```

Comment: Please show the template `job/jobs.html`.

Comment: You use a {% url 'job_detail' parameter %} with empty parameter. Most certainly a mistake in setting the context in your view.